Spectral abscissa of a real matrix achieved at a real eigenvector
Consider a real matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ with eigenvalues $\left\{\lambda_i\in\mathbb{C}\right\}_{i\in[N]}$ and the spectral abscissa $\alpha(A)=\max_{\lambda_i(A)}Re(\lambda_i)$ achieved at $\lambda_k$, with an associated eigenvector $v_k$.
Under what conditions is the associated eigenvector real, i.e., $v_k\in\mathbb{R}^N$?
The Perron–Frobenius theorem answers this question for matrices with only positive or only negative entries because the spectral Pesson radius $r$ is also the spectral abscissa, and the theorem guarantees that the associated eigenvector is real.
As real eigenvalues are associated with real eigenvectors, an alternative way of putting this question would be, under what conditions might the spectral abscissa of a real matrix be achieved in a non-real eigenvalue?
